# Как считать число из файла Node.js

Tags: node.js, файлы

Есть файл в котором число записей в базе. И мне необходимо вытянуть число из файла:
Я пытаюсь вот так :

```
fs.readFile("./files_to_help/QuoteNum.txt",{encoding:'utf8'},(err,data)=>{
             var ret=0+data;
             return ret;

   });
```

Но получаю `undefined` Мне необходимо чтоб содержимое вернулось в формате `int`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно проверить результат на ошибки. Первым аргументом идёт err, это и будет возможная ошибка. Вы в результате работы получаете undefined, это косвенно говорит о том, что в результате работы как раз и произошла ошибка. Могу предполагать, что неправильный путь.

Если же всё верно, сперва необходимо привести аргументы явно, через Number(data). А потом результат что это не NaN. И только потом складывайте.

Следующая ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь вернуть данные из коллбэка, а значит у вас нет понимания асинхронности. Попробуйте для начала разобраться в этом.